# Option "take this to the chat" earlier

Tags: feature-request

after about 10 comments to and fro in a short time, SE suggest to "take the discussion to a chat". Often, that would have been useful about 10 comments earlier.

Is there a way to make this appear earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been requests for this on the mother meta ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat)) but so far nothing has been implemented.

You can, of course, go to chat, create a room, and invite the other user.

Comment: As long as the other user has sufficient reputation...